# Java, linking JFrame to different class

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, implements

I am new to Java and have set myself the task of creating a calculator that calculated Austudy (welfare) payments based on certain variables. I have the main class working correctly which does all the calculations. I am now attempting to build a GUI using JForm to interact with it. I understand fundamentally how this will work, however I am unsure how to get my GUI class to recognise the variables that I wish to change in the Calculator class.

Git links below for the src files ("CentrelinkCalculator" class is unused):

https://github.com/daneroe/Austudy/tree/master/AustudyCalculator/src

As a first step, I am trying to get the radio buttons in the GUI to switch the "cases" in the AustudyCalculator.. class. However it does not recognise this as a local variable. Is it a case of needing to create an interface and "implement" a class?

Comment: Read up MVC design pattern. Implement a class to centrally hold your data.

Comment: You first need to devise a concept of a (or more) "model", which holds the data and can perform operations on it